# C# Double won't give correct result from arithmetics

Tags: c#, math, double

I was learning back the basics of C# Programming. I'm trying to build arithmetics with double variables, but it seems won't work properly. here's the code

```
        double num1, num2;
        Console.Write("First Number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("second number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Result : " + (num1 + num2));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

but the problem is on Run. i tried to make 3 + 4.3 hoping it will give me 7.3, but instead, it shows 46 (even minus the dots!). anybody know why this is happening? it seems there's some problem with the software settings on my Visual Studio (2019).

Comment: The Culutre of your system seams to not use decimal point (`.`) but something different like the decimal comma `,` in e.g. german. Use `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to convert without the system culture changing the expected format

Comment: thx a lot. i never realized that just now